# intersystem cache C# query with name like?

Tags: c#, caching, intersystems

I am trying to use like in  a Cache sql query such as:

```
select * from person where name like ?.
```

I am passing the parameter like below.

```
CacheParameter param = new CachemParameter("NAME", CacheDBType.NVarChar);
param.Value = tbxName.Text.ToUpper();
command.parameters.Add(param);
```

Then I execute the reader.

The results is nothing.
I know in MSSQL I use name like 'Lawson%'. How do I do this in a Cache query?

TIA
Mike

Answer (score 1):

According to the [doc example](http://docs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GBMP_ado#GBMP_ado_queries)

Your command could use `%STARTSWITH` instead of `like`:

```
select * from person where name %STARTSWITH ?
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out that all I had to do was to concatenate the "%" to the parameter being passed and it worked such as:
    param.Value = tbxName.Text.ToUpper() + "%";

Comment: Beware that using `like` you risk the user typing the `%` character on the text box, or leaving it blank.